# How does GitHub know which user cloned a repo?

Tags: git, github, clone, git-clone

I'm not asking how do *I* know who cloned my repo. I'm asking how does *GitHub* know that I'm the one who cloned the repo, and not some other account.

If someone else cloned my repo, how does git know that's a different user and not me? Could someone clone my repo, and contribute/push directly to it from their account? Could someone else clone my repo, and pretend to be me and contribute/push to it?

Comment: if it's an open repo, there is no authentication involved, so github does not know who cloned it.... however, if it's private, there is some authentication taking place and then github knows who does it (or could plainly reject the cloning from taking place if the user is not authorized to get access to it).

Comment: But when I commit to my repo on GitHub, it shows my username next to the commit

Comment: that is just github noticing that the user/email that shows up in a commit (which can be any value, by the way.... i can setup whatever values I want in `user.name` and `user.email` when I commit) is a user that they have registered in their system..... _and_ it has no relation to cloning a repo.... so, I don't understand where you are going.

Comment: Damn, you're right. I should have reworded my question - I want to know how GitHub knows who made a given commit. Based off what you said, GitHub is only guessing based off the `user.name` and `user.email` ? If so, could anybody push to my public repo as long as they set their `user.name` and `user.email` to the same as mine (I'm the only contributor)?

Comment: Nope. Pushing requires authentication (no relation to `user.name` or `user.email`). And GitHub has no access to your `user.name` and `user.email` values.  Those values are used by git when a commit is done... And GitHub uses whatever author is set in a commit when a commit is analyzed.

Comment: Aaaah, right. Thank you! I researched a bit based on what you said, and it seems my username and password information were automatically stored in a credentials manager (or I just forgot putting them in ). Wish I could mark your comment as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

github doesn't know who cloned a repo. any one can clone a public repo and it's not a problem. when pushing to github, the github uses your `ssh public key` to construct and send you a challenge. this challenge is a message which is encrypted with your `public key` and only you (the holder of `private key`) can decrypt the message and send the proper response. if you solve the challenge, you can push otherwise github doesn't let you push.

the public key can be used just for encrypting so you can share it with any one and only the private key can be used for decrypting. for more information about ssh key look at [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SSH_keys#Background). you can also use GPG keys, the concept is similar.

when it comes to git, git simply uses the config `user.name` and `user.email` so it can be any string. someone can use your username and email and this doesn't affect the github authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else cannot contribute if your repository was private and not invited to others as contributor as well.

if your repository private then no one can access it by searching it on github.

github is identifying which user contributed this repo using authentication. if you use git you have to include your credential to git as well to push some changes.

Comment: What if my repo is public?